# Is it possible and meaningful to make the superclass abstract?

Tags: java

I am told that: a class can extend a concrete superclass and override an implemented method to make it abstract.

If the method becomes abstract, then the corresponding superclass should become abstract too.

Is this correct? If so, is it meaningful to make the superclass or the method in superclass to become abstract?

Answer (score 0):

To contain abstract methods the class itself must also be declared abstract.

Abstract methods can be used where behaviour is specific to each subclassing object. Although this can also be achieved through interfaces, you may prefer to use an abstract class as they can also contain already implemented methods, or you may wish to declare fields which are not *static* and *final*. Beware that when a class becomes abstract it can no longer be instantiated.

Read more about abstract classes [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html).

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not you make your class abstract if it contains abstract methods is not a choice, it is a must. You **cannot have a non-abstract class that has abstract methods**.

Whether or not you should **declare a method abstract** or implement it in your super class comes down to your concrete use case. Is there a default behavior that makes sense for all possible concrete implementations of the super class? Then you might want to implement it. If that's not the case, declare it abstract and let the sub classes take over.

Answer (score 0):

> I am told that: a class can extend a concrete superclass and override an implemented method to make it abstract.
>
> If the method becomes abstract, then the corresponding superclass should become abstract too.
>
> Is this correct?

I think it's incorrect.

Take the following code for example.

```
public class Father {
    public void print() {
        System.out.println("Father");
    }
}

public abstract class Son extends Father {
    @Override
    public abstract void print(); /* no need to abstract the superclass */

    // and other abstract or concrete methods
}

public class Grandson extends Son {
    @Override
    public void print() {
        System.out.println("Grandson");
    }
}
```